# What is a good PCB that you can fit with 8AWG wires?

Tags: power, pcb, wiring

Me and a couple of other students are working on a school project that is using voltage up to 100v and 40amps.  So I figured the that 8AWG wires are the ones to to use for this. They are pretty thick wires compared to the wires I would use for an Arduino. So since they are pretty thick, it does not look like they can be fitted onto regular PCB.  Anyone know where I can find PCBs to that can fit them?

Comment: Isn't it just a matter of using the correct size drill/pad in your layout?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel no, it isn't just a matter of hole size.  You wouldn't want to solder wires that large through a hole, you'd solder them parallel to the copper or else bolt a crimped ring contact to the board, such that the hole would pass the clamping bolt but the surface contact would be for the electrical contact.  If you needed to get to an inner layer you'd have lots of ordinary vias, not a few large plated holes.

Answer (score 2):

Using your favorite Internet search engine perform a search using the keywords "pcb wire-to-board connector". You'll discover multiple companies that manufacture (e.g., Molex, AVX, TE Connectivity, etc.) and distribute/sell (Newark, Mouser, Digi-Key, etc.) wire-to-board connector products. Plan B would be to visit an electronics parts distributor website (Newark, Digi-Key, Mouser, etc.) and use the site's search tools to find the connector products they sell. You can also request a printed catalog from a parts distributor (Newark, Mouser, Digi-Key, etc.). Sometimes it's easier to find the parts you want by perusing a distributor's printed catalog versus searching the distributor's website.

For what it's worth, if wire flexibility is a concern, have you considered using multiple smaller gauge wires, rather than using a single 8 AWG wire, to deliver the 100V/40A power, where each wire carries only a portion of the 40A maximum current?  For example, if you create an eight-wire harness where each wire is the same wire gauge, then each wire carries roughly 40A/8 = 5A. Each of these eight wires can be much smaller, the mounting holes in the PCB can be smaller, the wire-to-board connectors can be smaller, etc. If you do this you'll need to be careful about how the individual wires are bundled together, encased, etc., to manage and prevent unwanted heating.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to build something that required #8 wire, I would do my best to keep the #8 wires away from the PC board.

To safely handle 40 Amps on a PC board, you would need very wide traces, and very thick copper on the board

Comment: #8 wire is 6 awg. Let's not mix measurements.

Comment: #8 wire would mean 8 AWG in the US, although it is not common.  In what context does #8 mean 6 AWG?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a relay, or contactor, which would enable you to use a smaller wire on the PCB and route that wire to the relay, mounted remotely.

Comment: What makes you think the goal is simple on/off switching?  The likely reason for bringing such power onto a board would be for more complex electronic switching, for example synthesizing one or more sine waves or at least PWM speed control.

Comment: Kinda hard to know without more info from the poster.   Without such data,  I just call 'em the way I see 'em.    Most everything is switching in electronics.    Relays, Contactors, Transistors, Oscillators (switching directions), Digital electronics is either 1 or 0 (switched), and even memory.   Oh, and switches.

Comment: The point is that relays aren't suitable for the switching involved in PWM type power modulation.

Comment: The question doesn't mention PWM modulation.

Comment: It doesn't mention switching either.

Comment: Most electronics is switching.